# Build generated Java projects with Maven

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I want to write a pom.xml for my project with the following steps :

1. Download a proprietary source generator from our repository (Sonatype Nexus)
2. Execute the sources generator to generate Java projects
3. Build the generated projects

I don't know how to write the pom.xml file for the step 3 in order to build the generated projects.

Before doing anything, there is only the pom.xml file. 
Once generated, it looks like this :

```
|--> pom.xml
|
|--> .repository
|    |--> Generator.exe
|
|--> Project1
|    |--> pom.xml
|    |--> src/main/java/project1
|
|--> Project2
|    |--> pom.xml
|    |--> src/main/java/project2
```

The generated projects are like Maven modules.

I started to write the file pom.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.maven</groupId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>foobar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>foobar</name>

    <properties>
        <repository.directory>${project.basedir}/.repository</repository.directory>

        <dependency.codegenerator.version>1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</dependency.codegenerator.version>       
        <dependency.codegenerator.directory>${repository.directory}</dependency.codegenerator.directory>
        <dependency.codegenerator.exe>${repository.directory}/Generator.exe</dependency.codegenerator.exe>      
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        
            <!-- Get generator -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>                             
                                <!-- Generator-->
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>generator</artifactId>
                                    <version>${dependency.codegenerator.version}</version>
                                    <classifier>bin_x64</classifier>
                                    <type>zip</type>
                                    <outputDirectory>${dependency.codegenerator.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                    <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Generate -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Generate sources phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-projects</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${dependency.codegenerator.exe}</executable>
                            <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}</workingDirectory>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>${project.basedir}</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I could add an execution to launch another Maven on each project but there might be a more elegant way.

Comment: What is the purpose of the source generator? What kind of projects are generated? Do you regenerate all the projects regularly?

Comment: How would you do it by hand?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.

I created empty directories (with pom.xml) which simulates the generated projects as Maven modules.

I added a Maven module which will generate the other modules.

So the directories are initially now :

```
|--> pom.xml        
|
|--> ProjectGeneration
|    |--> pom.xml
|
|--> Project1
|    |--> pom.xml
|
|--> Project2
|    |--> pom.xml
```

The new main pom.xml references all the projects as Modules:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.maven</groupId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>foobar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>foobar</name>
        
    <modules>
        <module>ProjectGeneration</module>
        <module>Project1</module>
        <module>Project2</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

I moved the content of the main pom.xml to the ProjectGeneration module.